# Angular sync the same directive?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am building a kind of social network where I have an angular directive which click on will follow a person. The follow button will appear next to the person's post. So if a person post 3 times the button will be repeated 3 times. But when I click on one follow button, the other 2 not showing the same result. they are remain the same.

So the question is how can I sync the other 2 buttons?

This is how my code working. This is a user's post, it has a like button at the bottom right
[image]

And this is when I click on the post, it will have the modal pop up show more detail about the post just like when you click on an image in facebook.

[image]

Then problem is when I click thumb up in the modal pop up it does not sync with the thumb up in the original one
[image]

This is the vote code

```
VoteButtons.link = function (scope, ele, att) {
var post_id = att.voteButtons;
scope.up_vote_class = 'default';
scope.down_vote_class = 'default';
scope.up_votes_number = 0;
scope.down_votes_number = 0;
scope.post_id = post_id
var up_votes_id = [];
var down_votes_id = [];
if (post_id) {
  $http.get('/api/posts/get-votes/' + post_id).success(function (res) {
    if (res && !res.error) {
      up_votes_id = res.response.up_votes;
      down_votes_id = res.response.down_votes;
      if (up_votes_id) {
        scope.up_votes_number = up_votes_id.length;
      }

      if (down_votes_id) {
        scope.down_votes_number = -down_votes_id.length;
      }

      if ($rootScope.user && up_votes_id && up_votes_id.indexOf($rootScope.user._id) != -1) {
        scope.up_vote_class = 'success';
      }

      if ($rootScope.user && down_votes_id && down_votes_id.indexOf($rootScope.user._id) != -1) {
        scope.down_vote_class = 'danger';
      }

    }
  })

  scope.thumb_up = function () {
    $http.post('/api/posts/up-vote/' + post_id).success(function (res) {
      if (res && !res.error) {
        up_votes_id = res.response.up_votes;
        down_votes_id = res.response.down_votes;
        if (up_votes_id) {
          scope.up_votes_number = up_votes_id.length;
        }

        if (down_votes_id) {
          scope.down_votes_number = -down_votes_id.length;
        }

        if ($rootScope.user && up_votes_id && up_votes_id.indexOf($rootScope.user._id) != -1) {
          scope.up_vote_class = 'success';
          Socket.emit('thumb_up',res.response)
        } else {
          scope.up_vote_class = 'default';
        }

        if ($rootScope.user && down_votes_id && down_votes_id.indexOf($rootScope.user._id) != -1) {
          scope.down_vote_class = 'danger';
        } else {
          scope.down_vote_class = 'default';
        }

      } else {
        $rootScope.alerts = res.error.message;
      }
    })
  }

  scope.thumb_down = function () {
    $http.post('/api/posts/down-vote/' + post_id).success(function (res) {
      if (res && !res.error) {
        up_votes_id = res.response.up_votes;
        down_votes_id = res.response.down_votes;
        if (up_votes_id) {
          scope.up_votes_number = up_votes_id.length;
        }

        if (down_votes_id) {
          scope.down_votes_number = -down_votes_id.length;
        }

        if ($rootScope.user && up_votes_id && up_votes_id.indexOf($rootScope.user._id) != -1) {
          scope.up_vote_class = 'success';
        } else {
          scope.up_vote_class = 'default';
        }

        if ($rootScope.user && down_votes_id && down_votes_id.indexOf($rootScope.user._id) != -1) {
          scope.down_vote_class = 'danger';
        } else {
          scope.down_vote_class = 'default';
        }
      } else {
        $rootScope.alerts = res.error.message;
      }
    })
  }
}
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure if this question is pertinent here but well... Each profile must have a list of followers, when you click 'follow', update that list with the new name/id, use that scope object to manage the directive. 

Your question has no code or specifics, neither does my answer.

Comment: Please provide your code and be a bit more specific what behaviour/result you expect when the button is clicked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To communicate the change to all of the other directive instances, you could make use of a pub/sub style. This could be done by having an event being broadcast using `$rootScope.$broadcast` that passes possibly the iD of the new thing being followed.

The event can then be listened for by all of your directives and upon callback check whether the directive is linked to that thing being followed. If so, update the state of the button.

Hard to explain, but I hope you can understand the logic of my approach.

And, hope it helps you out!